# Using TextEncoding in TS 2.8 with Angular 6

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I'm having a heck of a time getting TextEncoding to import in TS 2.8. I'm installed from npm and attempted to import us follows:

```
import { TextDecoder } from 'text-encoding';
```

alternatively

```
import { } from 'text-encoding';
```

But I receive the following error trying to build in VS regardless of whether I even try to implement TextDecoder in code.

> node_modules/@types/text-encoding/index.d.ts(25,40): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'TextDecoderOptions'.
>
> node_modules/@types/text-encoding/index.d.ts(25,61): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'TextDecoder'.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you install the [text-encoding types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/text-encoding)?

Comment: read [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/24695)

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc - that certainly seems to be part of the issue. However I'm still getting a build error "Cannot find name 'TextDecoder'" after uninstalling @types/text-encoding. Is there an import I need to include do you know?

Comment: You cannot import textdecoder like that, you have to add the js file to the angular.json and just declare const TextDecoder: any;

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks for the information. I will try this shortly and get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

i have a solution but it's depends because i use some npm packages with angular...

polyfill for all browser in https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-encoding-polyfill

```
npm i text-encoding-polyfill
```

and types for being compatible with TS in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/text-encoding

```
npm i @types/text-encoding
```

and finaly into angular app using this import

```
import { TextEncoder } from 'text-encoding-polyfill';
```

later of that you can use you `let encoder = new TextEnconder()`

I hope this can help U, it solve my problem

Comment: `text-encoding-polyfill` does not pass `npm audit --production`